# Why don't pandas DataFrame objects support boolean evaluation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe, is there some specific reason that direct boolean evaluation isn't supported? Contrary to the pandas error message, it seems absolutely clear and completely unambiguous how to evaluate the truth-value of a dataframe.

What case would a dataframe with `shape 0,0` would anyone not want `bool(df) -> False`? What would that break, or enable, that would be bad?

Conversely, if you have a dataframe with `sum(shape) > 0`, what would ever not make sense, break, or be enabled by letting `bool(df) -> True`?

**Not asking for philosophy**, just like an example or specific reason. To me, it seems very clear how useful this would be, and very opaque that it isn't supported. The error message itself led me to understand the exact opposite of the error message, it almost seems like satire after thinking about it.

In my work the result is, I can't have dataframes flow through a logic system that applies generally, instead i have to make a special case for this single type of data object to use the `empty` method instead of simply evaluating it in a general condition statement for example.

```
if a: do_something()
else: do_something_else()
```

When a is a dataframe, I have to add code to achieve the obvious expected result. It is the only data object I'm working with that requires a separate method to check if it's empty and equate that to being `false`.

Obviously I can write

`if a or (if type(a) is DataFrame and sum(a.shape)>0: do_something`

or

`if a or not getattr(a, "empty"): do_something`

or whatever, tiptoeing around which part of the condition goes where to carefully not bool the dataframe or hardcode the object-specific methods (as I didn't do in these examples).

As written above, the question is what specific harm is avoided by forcing these approaches?

If your answer is to agree with the pandas error message about ambiguity, I guess my question would be what is unambiguous about an all-zero shape being `False` and any other shape `True`. Its a fundamental aspect of Python's builtin datatypes that objects with 'shape' are `True`, and objects that are empty / without shape / zero length are `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People constantly screw up boolean operations with arrays and dataframes, expecting `if` checks to broadcast. From what I've seen, this is much more common than people trying to check a dataframe for emptiness. Banning `__bool__` helps catch these errors, rather than producing silent misbehavior.

Also, you expect any shape with at least one nonzero dimension to be considered True. That's not what I would expect from an emptiness check, and it's not what `DataFrame.empty` does. I would expect something that behaves like `DataFrame.empty`: a dataframe is considered empty if it has at least one zero-length dimension.

Comment: After a year or so working with pandas, I suppose I've come to think of an empty df with defined columns as a container with empty containers, like a list [[]] where bool([[]]) is true.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a special case for each `if`, make a special function for possible conversions

```py
def coerce_to_bool(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, "empty"):
        return obj.empty
    return bool(obj)
```

```py
    if coerce_to_bool(df):
       ...
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. willy-nilly methods are all good fun, and subclasses to support more complex behavior. this is in the catetory of "tiptoeing" that i describe, all you did was move the tiptoeing into a function. I'm not going to type out every possible workaround that are essentially variations of tiptoeing, thanks. i'm asking about the pandas idea about bool(df) being ambiguous and not supported, hence the question.